# Play Framework Task Example H2 Error - Fixed

Tags: playframework

Been trying out the Play framework and am going through the tutorial.  However I keep getting a very specific error -

[PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Table "TASK" not found; SQL statement: select t0.id c0, t0.label c1 from task t0 [42102-168] Bind values:[null] Query was: select t0.id c0, t0.label c1 from task t0 ]

...associated code

```
23   public static List<Task> all() {
24     return find.all();
25   }
```

Reading the forums I have tried stopping and re-starting the H2 db but it doesn't seem to work.

Update: 
I assume that the Play tutorial would speak to creating a table in H2 if that was required. But as a commenter stated, I checked via the console and the table does not exist.  I will try moving forward by creating a table and deriving the schema but the tutorial needs to be updated if I'm not missing something.  Bad assumption on my part.

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaTodoList 
Apple MacBook Pro Retina 10.7.5, Java 6

Update 2: 
Ran the following but still get the same error

```
create table task (id varchar(256) primary key, label varchar(256));
```

My application.conf

```
 db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
 db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"

 db.default.user=sa
 db.default.password=""
 ...
 ebean.default="models.*"
 evolutionplugin=disabled
```

Update 3: 
    Thanks to those who have responded.  I do have ebean.default value setup in my application.conf.  Evolution plugin is disabled.  Just learning Play/H2 it seems that my application (and associated configuration) is not able to access the H2 db.  I would start the H2 console and add the table 'TASK' but running the sample app still gives the error (Yes I also committed to db).  I have also tried to run the app without the H2 console but that logically won't work as the H2 TASK table isn't persisted.  Not really sure what else to look through at this point but I'm sure it's obvious...I hope.

Update 4:  Fixed 
   Enabling the evolution plugin worked.  Not that this makes sense to me right now (will have to explore evolution a bit).  So in short, the tutorial should tell folks that for the Java TODO to work, they need to go into the h2-console from the play command line and run create table, have the instance up when starting the app.

   Sorry this update took some time.  Just got back to this after other issues took hold.

Comment: First, could you add the link to the page of the tutorial you're working on.  Second, can you add your database connection properties the question.  Thirdly, can you interrogate the H2 database w/o the Play code to determine if the "task" table really exists?

Comment: Did you add `ebean.default="models.*"` to your `application.conf`?

Comment: If you find an answer to your question you should post it as an answer, not an edit to your question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try to update  evolutionplugin=disabled with  evolutionplugin=enable then it should work.